# React JS, how to show state in two pages

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

I am currently developing a website for counting points, the user can give points to each player. The total of all points are calculated and shown below the counters on the administrator page. Now what I want is that I also want to show the total value in a different page, where players can see how much points their team has scored. But this total value has to be in sync with the total value in the administrator page. How can I do this? I heard about axios, but have no idea how this works. Can someone help me?

---

## My Code:

### Counter

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        const { onIncrement, onDecrement } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                <button onClick={() => onIncrement(this.props.counter)}>
                    Add
                </button>

                <button
                    onClick={() => onDecrement(this.props.counter)}
                    disabled={this.props.counter.value === 0 ? "disabled" : ""}
                >
                    Delete
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    formatCount() {
        const { value } = this.props.counter;
        return value;
    }
}

if (document.getElementById("counter")) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById("counter"));
}
```

### Counters

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Counter from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            counters: [
                { id: 1, value: 0 },
                { id: 2, value: 0 },
                { id: 3, value: 0 },
                { id: 4, value: 0 },
                { id: 5, value: 0 }
            ],
            total: 0
        };
    }
    handleIncrement(counter) {
        const total = this.state.total + 1;
        const counters = [...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index] = { ...counter };
        counters[index].value++;
        this.setState({ counters: counters, total: total });
    }

    handleDecrement(counter) {
        const total = this.state.total - 1;
        const counters = [...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index] = { ...counter };
        counters[index].value--;
        this.setState({ counters: counters, total: total });
    }

    handleReset() {
        const total = 0;
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
            c.value = 0;
            return c;
        });
        this.setState({ counters: counters, total: total });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleReset.bind(this)}>Reset</button>
                {this.state.counters.map(counter => (
                    <Counter
                        key={counter.id}
                        onIncrement={this.handleIncrement.bind(this)}
                        onDecrement={this.handleDecrement.bind(this)}
                        counter={counter}
                    />
                ))}
                <span>{this.state.total}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Counters;

if (document.getElementById("counters")) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Counters />, document.getElementById("counters"));
}
```

Comment: You should look at using shared state via a framework like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios is an http client so that wouldn't apply to your problem.

Theres multiple solutions to your problem.

**Option #1: Callbacks**

Depending on how your admin and non-admin page is structured/nested this option might be easy or difficult to implement.

You could have a parent component that holds all your counter value data and renders either your admin or non-admin component that shows your counters.

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counters: [
                { id: 1, value: 0 },
                { id: 2, value: 0 },
                { id: 3, value: 0 },
                { id: 4, value: 0 },
                { id: 5, value: 0 }
            ],
            total: 0
        };
    }

    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/admin" render={() => <Admin counters={this.state.counters} total={this.state.total} />}/>
                <Route exact path="/user" render={() => <Admin counters={this.state.counters} total={this.state.total} />}/>
            </Switch> 
        );
    }
}
```

This will keep in sync because the counters are only being stored in one place, the Parent component.

**Option #2: Global state management library**

The alternative is a state management library like Redux. This gives you a global state that does not get deleted when a component is unmounted unlike your local `this.state`. You would put counters into this global state then your admin would perform actions on it, like increment and decrement, and admin and non-admin components would fetch counter values from it similar to local state by calling `this.props.reduxStateCounters`, for example.

More can be read about Redux [here](https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist).

Comment: Thank you, I will look into using redux further.